# let keyword always show not defined error in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, let

I have below part of code:

```
if (this.holdReasonList.length == 1 || this.holdReasonList == undefined || this.holdReasonList.length == 0) {
            return this._cciDataService.getHoldReasonDropList()
                .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
                .subscribe((res) => {
                    if (res.Success) {
                        let defaultList = [];
                        res.Data.forEach((reason: string) => {
                            defaultList.push(reason.trim());
                        })
```

I always got undefined error of `defaultList` after I called this line:

```
let defaultList = [];
```

I do not understand why `defaultList` is not defined since I clearly declared it.

Thanks for the help in advance!

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the advice! Since I tried put the `let defaultList=[]` outiside the whole piece of the subscribe block, it works now.

But the reason is not clear. I set the break point and type `let defaultList = []` in the console and it also returns undefined. Please see below screenshot:
[image]

I think I do not need to even think of where the `defaultList` to be used, the `defualtList` is undefined right after the declaration. I do not have any chance to even use its value....

Comment: Have you tried moving `let defaultList = [];`  outside of the `res.success` catch?

Comment: You mean the return value, that you think is `defaultList`, is `undefined`? If so then this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: `let` statement declares a block-scoped local, so `defaultList` can be accessed inside `if` block only, if you;'re trying access outside of the block it will throw undefined error

Comment: Where are your using this defaultList ?  If you are using this variable outside the subscription then keep it outside.

Comment: exactly, the code provided by OP should work fine @DurgeshPal

Comment: @DurgeshPal I use it only inside the if(res.Success) block. But it is undefined right after declaration.

Comment: @OliverHeward Thanks for the advice! Yes I put the variable outside the whole subscription block and it works. But I still do not understand why defaultList is underfined. Please see my updated question,

Comment: No problem @wadefanyaoxia :) Personally I couldn’t give you a straight answer as you’re probably better than I am, my only thing would be that it’s a variable defined with let. Try changing it to const and see what the result is although I expect it to be the same output... this is why we all have a love hate relationship with JavaScript 

Answer (score 0):

Ok. When I debug on Chrome devTool, the variable is defined....The issue was that I was debugging by using VSCode.

Be aware that `let` keyword will cause undefined variable on VSCode debugger.